How to get Install Shield to register COM+ DLLs
Steps to get Install Shield to register COM+ DLLs.
Search on the internet for information but did not find anything helpful.
This command can be used to register the DLL and create all the registry entries needed.
Need to understand the process.

You can use Regsvr32 C:\Path\To\YourDllFile.dll to register a DLL and create registry entries
